# tab in Android - tabView or ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, tabview

I want to do something like [this](https://lh5.ggpht.com/S28Kqz5Xj3ERRPI1SrLxh_dm7kbJ3qaYtCdMvTObH8CzRAlU2QuI4hq_3QewoCA_Ji7x)
I have read through the tutorial about TabView and later aboout ActionBar and Fragments. I am confused.

Please can someone tells me which of the TabView or ActionBar will allow me to draw a Tab like in the given link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking because of "More" tab. I believe it is `tab view` for sure.
This [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) show how to make it so.

Comment: With the new version of the SDK, when you create a project, you can choose to build an app with tab. so everything is generated but the activity_main.xml only with FrameLayout. Ok let's modify my code following the given link.

Comment: But at the end , I have 5 Tabs and all of them cannot enter at once. I don't want to scroll horizontaly to view the other Tabs. So I think to put this: Tab1 - Tab2 - More. Where More is arrow dropdown list containing Tab3 - Tab4 - Tab5. So how can I manage to get this ?